# How does reference cycle creates a memory leak in those browsers which implement reference counting garbage collection in JavaScript? In detail?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, reference-counting

Reading the MDN docs about memory management in JS, I came across the following code:

```
function f(){
  var o = {};
  var o2 = {};
  o.a = o2; // o references o2
  o2.a = o; // o2 references o

  return "azerty";
}

f();
// Two objects are created and reference one another thus creating a cycle.
// They will not get out of the function scope after the function call, so they
// are effectively useless and could be free'd.
// However, the reference-counting algorithm considers that since each of both
// object is referenced at least once, none can be garbage-collected.
```

But how does it work internally and why it creates a memory leak?

Here is how I understand it:

```
1) `f();`: function f gets called;

2) `var o = {};`: an object is instantiated (memory looks like this):
       ________
      | Object |
      |________|
           ^
           |
           |
           o (the symbol 'o' is a reference to an Object allocated in memory)


3) `var o2 = {};`: another object is instantiated, now memory looks like this: 

       ________                        ________    
      | Object |                      | Object |
      |________|                      |________|
           ^                               ^
           |                               |
           |                               |
           o                               o2


4) `o.a = o2; // o references o2` and `o2.a = o; // o2 references o`: memory now looks like this (correct me if I'm wrong):

       ________                         ________    
      | Object | <-     -------------> | Object |
      |________|   |   /               |________|
           ^        --/---------             ^
           |         /          \            |
           |        /            \           |
           o       /              \          o2
            \--> .a                .a <-----/
```

5) What happens when the function returns and why does the memory leak
   arise? `o = null` and `o2 = null`? How does the memory look now graphically?

Thanks for the attention. I have searched a lot for a detailed answer about the topic but couldn't find useful infos.